# Open autocomplete list when textbox is clicked

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to use autocomplete input text box feature in my angular project.

So I try to use typeahead directive in my input text box.

Here the module defenition:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("damageEvent", ["ui.router",
        "geomindCommon",
        "lookups",
        "ngAnimate",
        "ui.bootstrap"])

        .config([
            "$stateProvider",
            function ($stateProvider) {

                $stateProvider
                  .state("sitesDamages", {
                      abstract: true,
                      url: "/sitesDamages",
                      template: "<ui-view></ui-view>"

                  })
                  .state("sitesDamages.sitesList", {
                      url: "/",
                      templateUrl: "app/damageEvent/templates/sitesDamageEvents.tmpl.html",
                      controller: "sitesDamageEventsController",
                      controllerAs: "list",
                  })
            }
        ]);
})();
```

Here is controller defenition:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module('damageEvent').controller("sitesDamageEventsController", [ sitesDamageEventsController]);


    function sitesDamageEventsController() {
        var self = this;

        self.selected = '';
        self.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas',
                        'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware',
                        'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois',
                        'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
                        'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
                        'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada',
                        'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota',
                        'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
                        'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia',
                        'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];

    }
})();
```

And here is HTML Template:

```
<div class="container">

        <input type="text"
               typeahead-min-length="0"
               ng-model="list.selected"
               typeahead="state for state in list.states | filter:$viewValue:emptyOrMatch | limitTo:8"
               class="form-control">

    </div>
```

Here how it looks in the view:

[image]

When I focus on input text box and start print inside it the autocomplete list popup.

But I need the autocomplete list popup when input text box is clicked (focused).

I use ui-bootstrap version Version: 0.14.2 and angularjs version 1.4.7.

Any idea is it possible to make popup autocomplete list when text box is focused?

Answer (score 1):

Try using typeahead-min-length="0", this [PR](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/d859f42cc022a5d8779f1c7b358486bbdd04ed57) was supposed to allow for that behavior.

***EDIT***
This feature is available in the 1.1.0 release.

Comment: But the last version of ui-bootstrap is 0.14.3 dosen't it?